# Variable value don't get update in while loop with python - selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, while-loop, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to load more elements and scroll as more elements as loaded(infinite scrolls where elements are loaded as your scroll)

> Problem : jobCards value changes only once and then don't change even though the loops run again,
> Does not even change for once if assigned any value to it before while loop runs

```
def totalJobs(self,):
    jobCards = self.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        'div[class^="job-cardstyle__JobCardHeader"]')
    return jobCards

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    jobCards = self.totalJobs()
    print("Total Jobs - " + str(len(jobCards)))
    self.execute_script(
        "arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth',block: 'center'});", jobCards[len(jobCards)-1])
    #Some break Condition based on len(jobCards)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're code looks fine, variable `jobCards` also gets update each time.

`totaljobs()` retuns list of elements which has always similar length.

for example when you scroll first time, same number elements loads on page.
**so always number of elements (len) are same.**

Can you please try to print elements instead of length of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `jobCards` is getting redefined every time. And you are just calling the function without adding previous length of the `jobCards` to it.

Try like below and confirm:

```
jobCards = [] # Make "jobCards" a class variable
def totalJobs(self,templist):
    templist = self.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^="job-cardstyle__JobCardHeader"]')
    return templist

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    jobCards = jobCards + self.totalJobs(templist = []) # Keeping adding new length to previous one.
    print("Total Jobs - " + str(len(jobCards)))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth',block: 'center'});", jobCards[len(jobCards)-1])
    #Some break Condition based on len(jobCards)
```